# What is the best practice to follow when creating a highly flexible HTML table?

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

I have one big table (with tabular data) queried from a MySQL table. Every column is sortable, All columns except one is optional (Users can click what columns to display) and different columns can be filtered with different search terms (Filter out search results even more).

I was wondering if there is already a way to follow in creating such a table, or will I have to implement it from scratch.

If I'm to implement it from scratch, advice me.

**Real bummer is that I can't use JavaScript.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an easy-to-do task, so I would do it from scratch (I actually did similar task recently).

The most irritating part seems to be avoiding JavaScript, as it is very handy to show forms for filtering columns with JavaScript. Though, that's the only place where I would use JavaScript, if editing data or opening it on row's onClick event is not needed. All other things can easily be done with plain HTML/PHP/SQL.

---

Function that might be handy for generating URLs:

```
/**
 * Returns URL with modifications based on $params.
 *
 * To remove parameter from URL, specify NULL as it's value.
 *
 * @param array $params
 * @param bool  $leaveUnescaped
 */
function modifyURL(array $params = null, $leaveUnescaped = false) {
    $url = '?' . http_build_query(array_merge($_GET, (array)$params));
    if ( !$leaveUnescaped ) {
        $url = html($url);
    }
    return $url;
}
```

Possible usage:

```
<tr>
    <th><a href='<?php echo modifyURL(array('sort_field' => 'id')); ?>'>ID</a></th>
    <th><a href='<?php echo modifyURL(array('sort_field' => 'name')); ?>'>Name</a></th>
</tr>
```

It's also good for making pagination links, i.e., `modifyURL(array('page' => $page))` or just `modifyURL(compact('page'))` in a loop.

---

For showing form for filtering column, you could use URL `modifyURL(array('filter_column' => 'name'))`. When generating table, check if `isset($_GET['filter_column'])` is true. If yes and if `$_GET['filter_column']` contains valid name of a column, print form for filtering appropriate column.

You will probably need multiple types of filtering forms - one for strings (single text field), one for dates (minimum date, maximum date), one for numbers (minimum number, maximum number). You might also need filtering form for enum-type data, i.e., with:

```
<select name='gender'>
    <option value='m'>male</option>
    <option value='f'>female</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Indeed it was the pagination that was getting kind of irritating with clean URLs, which made me ask the question. I think I'll go with the `get`.

Comment: Pagination is easy to do with that `modifyURL()`. Calculating `limit` and `offset` also should not be a problem, based on `$_GET['page']` and `$itemsPerPage`. You may consider using `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` with `FOUND_ROWS()` to get total number of items, though some say that it may be slower than 2 queries (one for data, another for number of total items); others say that it's faster. When generating links for pages, don't forget to "skip" large blocks of page numbers, e.g., show something like "1 2 3 ... 49 50 **51** 52 53 ... 98 99 100", if you have large number of pages.

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to be using CodeIgniter, have you checked out the Table Class?

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/table.html